# First time trigger help - am I being a bad neighbor or going to slow my org down?

Tags: trigger

Ok, my first trigger question was a bit more complicated ([First Time Trigger - correct loop to use question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46741/first-time-trigger-correct-loop-to-use-question)).
I'm taking a step back to simplify before I attempt the more complex. Good news my trigger does everything I want it to as it exists below, however when I try to add contact id maps, etc. it breaks. Will the trigger below slow my org (or anyone else's) down? If yes, How do I fix it without breaking it?
thanks  crop1645 for the edit tip!

```
//trigger purpose is to create new Key Buyer records connected to contacts & Jack plans when new or existing contacts have the Economic Decision-Maker box ticked

trigger CreateStakeholderEconDmaker on Contact (after insert, after update) {
    if (trigger.isInsert) {
        //every trigger has this loop & a list to hold all new records
        List<StakeholderContact__c> newkeybuyers = new List<StakeholderContact__c> ();


        //go through the list of contacts and get all the related plans

        //the map to hold all related plans for these contacts
        Map <Id, JACK_Prospect_Plan__c> Plans = new Map <Id, JACK_Prospect_Plan__c>();

        // go through the list of plans and add data into the map
        {

            For (JACK_Prospect_Plan__c Plan : [select id from JACK_Prospect_Plan__c where Id in :Plans.keyset ()]) {
                Plans.put (Plan.Id, Plan);
            }
            //Go through the list of contacts and create the stakeholders to write
            for (Contact C : Trigger.new) {
                //which contacts are we using, only contacts where a buyer field is true & account record plan id is not null
                If (C.ContPlanID__c != null && C.BuyerEconDMaker__c == true) {

                    //create a blank keybuyer
                    StakeholderContact__c Keybuyer = new StakeholderContact__c ();
                    //set the values
                    Keybuyer.JACK_Prospect_Plan__c = C.ContPlanID__c;
                    Keybuyer.ContactPlan1__c = C.Id;
                    KeyBuyer.KeyBuyerType__c = 'Economic Decision-Maker';

                    //stick the Keybuyer into the list we created earlier
                    newkeybuyers.add (Keybuyer);
                }

                // Save the key buyers
                Insert NewKeybuyers;
            }
        }
    } else if (trigger.isUpdate) {
        //trigger purpose is to create new Key Buyer records connected to contacts & Jack Attack plans when new or existing contacts have the Economic Decision-Maker box ticked
        //every trigger has this loop & a list to hold all new records
        List<StakeholderContact__c> newkeybuyerz = new List<StakeholderContact__c> ();

        //go through the list of contacts and get all the related plans

        //the map to hold all related plans for these contacts
        Map <Id, JACK_Prospect_Plan__c> Plans = new Map <Id, JACK_Prospect_Plan__c>();

        // go through the list of plans and add data into the map
        {

            For (JACK_Prospect_Plan__c Plan : [select id from JACK_Prospect_Plan__c where Id in :Plans.keyset ()]) {
                Plans.put (Plan.Id, Plan);
            }
            //Go through the list of contacts and create the stakeholders to write
            for (Contact Co : Trigger.new) {
                Contact cOld = trigger.OldMap.get (Co.Id);
                if (cOld.BuyerEconDMaker__c == false && Co.BuyerEconDMaker__c == true && Co.ContPlanID__c != null) {

                    //create a blank keybuyer
                    StakeholderContact__c Keybuyerz = new StakeholderContact__c ();
                    //set the values
                    Keybuyerz.JACK_Prospect_Plan__c = Co.ContPlanID__c;
                    Keybuyerz.ContactPlan1__c = Co.Id;
                    KeyBuyerz.KeyBuyerType__c = 'Economic Decision-Maker';

                    //stick the Keybuyer into the list we created earlier
                    newkeybuyerz.add (Keybuyerz);
                }

                // Save the key buyers
                Insert NewKeybuyerz;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to SFSE Vadmin -- please edit your post to make your code readable - use the {} command -- if you look at other posts you can see how it is done

Comment: thanks Vadmin -- you could help us out here more by indenting code sections so everything isn't left-aligned. SFSE members are good but they really appreciate well-formatted code to review if that is the task you are asking them

Comment: Thx, on a train...will reformat later.

Comment: As @crop1645 suggests, clear formatting will improve the chances of useful answers being posted. As it stands it looks to me like you are querying with an empty Plans.keyset() and doing Insert NewKeybuyers inside a loop when it should be outside and there are probably other problems too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main points:

- Use Java style syntax. Look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_syntax.htm)
- Try to stick to the same case mix - eg `newkeybuyers` and `NewKeybuyers` - probably should be referred to as `newKeyBuyers` throughout the trigger.
- You have an `insert` inside a `for` loop - remove from the loop (you have the right idea having a list to save to, but you are saving the list every time in the loop).
- You also have a list called `newkeybuyerz` in the second code block - best to use one list that is global to the whole trigger and just initialize it for each trigger dml type.

  `List<StakeholderContact__c> newKeyBuyers;`
  `if (trigger.isInsert) {`
      `newKeyBuyers = new List<StakeholderContact__c> ();`
      `....`

  `if (trigger.isUpdate) {`
      `newKeyBuyers = new List<StakeholderContact__c> ();`
- You have an unneeded curly braces pair at line  15 and 51. 
  While this will probably compile, it's not needed and will confuse other developers.
- Your `for` loop identifier is capitalised - which again, will probably compile, but will miss out being syntax highlighted and may confuse.
- You seem be adding to the Plans Map but not actually using it...
- One more thing - I'm guessing you need to fill plans based on some data from contacts.
  You should extract your plan id or contact id from contacts in a loop. Put it in a `Set<id>` object and use **THAT** in the plans query. Does that make sense?

I think the you have the right idea - make these changes and the code will be getting there.

Comment: I think I misread this question - I thought you just wanted a code review. I'll have another look...

Comment: Oh, I also formatted your whole trigger so it can be read.

Comment: Wow, many thanks @CasnNZ I was finally getting back to reformat & see that you responded & are a saint for updating it for me. I will be a better poster AND will update my trigger and test tomorrow. You've explained everything really well (I tried a bunch of different versions in the sandbox based on the dev guide, posts & other bp sites and just couldn't get some of the fundamentals to work right for what I needed to do. For example, instead of using 1 list as you explained above I made a new list). Yay @CaspNZ!!

Comment: Glad to help :)